# Magnetism as a relativistic effect

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

I am considering the following derivation for the Lorentz force from a wire.

[image]

[image]

I am having difficulty understanding why the Lorentz transformation for forces involves the term: $$\frac{1}{1-\frac{vu}{c^2}}$$. The 4-force is given by: $${\mathbf  {F}}=m{\mathbf  {A}}=\left(\gamma {{\mathbf  {f}}\cdot {\mathbf  {u}} \over c},\gamma {{\mathbf  f}}\right)$$ In this case we are considering a force purely in the y-direction so $${\mathbf  {f}}\cdot {\mathbf  {u}} = 0$$and the transformation is between frames with different x-velocities. Using the Lorentz transformation the force in S appears to be just f/γ. Where does the additional term come from?
[image]

Comment: This is only a suggestion from a brief look: the force $(f^{-}_y)'$ was calculated in the $S'$ frame, so that means it is proportional to the rate of change of the velocity of the charge $q$ in this same frame. We know that the charge $q$ is moving with speed $u$ to the right w.r.t frame $S$ *but* to find the correct speed w.r.t frame $S'$ which is itself moving to the right with speed $v$ requires the *velocity addition formula* which is exactly the expression where the term you are puzzled about appears. Again, I haven't verified this, but perhaps it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think I realized the issue. γ is determined by the speed relative to the test particle. Equating the 4-force gives: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-\frac{(v-u)^2}{(1-uv/c^2)^2c^2})}}f'_{y} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-\frac{u^2}{c^2})}}f_{y} $$
Some algebra then gives the above expression. Is this a standard expression or is there an obvious way to see this? My notes seemed to take it for granted.